# github api - fetch all commits of all repos of an organisation based on date

Tags: python, ruby, github, github-api

Assembla provides a simple way to fetch all commits of an organisation using `api.assembla.com/v1/activity.json`  and it takes to and from parameters allowing to get commits of selected date(from all the spaces(repos) the user is participating.

Is there any similar way in Github ?

I found these for Github:
`/repos/:owner/:repo/commits`
Accepts since and until parameters for getting commits of selected date. But, since I want commits from all repos, I have to loop over all those repos and fetch commits for each repo.

`/users/:user/events`
This shows the commits of a user. I dont have any problem looping over all the users in the org, but how can I get for a particular date ?

`/orgs/:org/events`
This shows commits of all users of all repos but dont know how to fetch for a particular date ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the `/users/:user/events` endpoint is that you just don't get the `PushEvent`s and you would have to skip over non-commit events and perform more calls to the API. Assuming you're authenticated, you should be safe so long as your users aren't hyper active.

For `/orgs/:org/events` I don't think they accept parameters for anything, but I can check with the API designers.

And just in case you aren't familiar, these are all paginated results. So you can go back until the beginning with the Link headers. My library ([github3.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py)) provides iterators to do this for you automatically. You can also tell it how many events you'd like. (Same with commits, etc). But yeah, I'll come back an edit after talking to the API guys at GitHub.

**Edit**: [Conversation](https://twitter.com/sigmavirus24/status/289043207340306432)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the GitHub Archive project -- http://www.githubarchive.org/, and the ability to query the archive using Google's BigQuery. Sounds like it would be a perfect tool for the job -- I'm pretty sure you could get exactly what you want with a single query.

The other option is to call the GitHub API -- iterate over all events for the organization and filter out the ones that don't satisfy your date rage criteria and event type criteria (commits). But since you can't specify date ranges in the API call, you will probably do a lot of calls to get the the events that interest you. Notice that you don't have to iterate over every page starting from 0 to find the page that contains the first result in the date range -- just do a (variation of) binary search over page numbers to find any page that contains a commit in the date range, a then iterate in both directions until you break out of the date range. That should reduce the number of API calls you make.